# How do I create multiple PHP arrays in a function for parameters passed by reference?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

If I have a function in php that creates several arrays of objects from parsing xml, how do I return those arrays as references?

Do I need to call new to allocate the arrays? How do I define them within the function?

```
function ParseConfig($rawxml, &$configName, &$radioArr, &$flasherArr, &$irdArr)
```

Sorry, I mean return multiple arrays as parameter references.

what do I do to create the array inside the function? or can I just start using it as an array?

Comment: What do you mean by "return those arrays as references"?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Comment: edited question...definatly should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't noticed that you edited your question, which changes things entirely.  You have two decent options here:

1. Explicitly change them at the top of the function:

   ```
   function foo($bar, &$baz, &$qux) {
       $baz = $qux = array();
   }
   ```
2. Perhaps this is a good place to introduce an object?

   ```
   class parseConfig {
       protected $rawXml;
       protected $configName;
       protected $radioArr   = array();
       protected $flasherArr = array();
       protected $irdArr     = array();

       public function __construct($raw_xml = null) {
           if (!is_null($raw_xml)) {
               $this->rawXml = $raw_xml;
               $this->parse();
           }
       }

       public function parse($raw_xml = null) {
           if (!is_null($raw_xml)) {
               $this->rawXml = $raw_xml;
           }

           if (empty($this->rawXml)) {
               return null;
           }

           $this->configName = '';
           $this->radioArr   =
           $this->flasherArr =
           $this->irdArr     = array();

           // parsing happens here, may return false

           return true;
       }

       public function setRawXml($raw_xml) {
           $this->rawXml = $raw_xml;
           return $this;
       }

       public function getRawXml() {
           return $this->rawXml;
       }

       public function getRadioArr() {
           return $this->radioArr;
       }

       public function getFlasherArr() {
           return $this->flasherArr;
       }

       public function getIrdArr() {
           return $this->irdArr;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use references in this case.  PHP uses a copy on write mechanism which also keeps track of the number of items pointing to the current value.  If you return a value from a function, and assign that result to a variable, the `refcount` will still only be one, since the variable used in the function will be destroyed when the function returns.  You can safely edit the variable containing the value returned from the function without worrying about wasting memory.

Sample test:

```
function getaz() { 
    $array = range('a','z'); 
    echo '2: ', memory_get_usage(), "\n";   
    return $array; 
}

echo '1: ', memory_get_usage(), "\n";
$p = getaz();
echo '3: ', memory_get_usage(), "\n";
$p[0] = '3';
echo '4: ', memory_get_usage(), "\n";
$p = array_merge($p, range('A','Z'));
echo '5: ', memory_get_usage();
```

Output:

```
1: 337304 [initial]
2: 340024 [inside function, value is created]
3: 340072 [outside function, value is assigned]
4: 340072 [element modified but remains same size]
5: 342696 [array extended]
```

If I change the function to return by reference, I get the following:

```
1: 337312 [it took 8 bytes more memory to define the function]
2: 340032 [accounting for the extra 8 bytes, no change]
3: 340080 [accounting for the extra 8 bytes, no change]
4: 340080 [accounting for the extra 8 bytes, no change]
5: 342704 [accounting for the extra 8 bytes, no change]
```

Hope this helps!

For some more reading on how and why this works this way, check out [this shameless blog plug that explains a little bit about how PHP deals with variables and values](http://www.dereleased.com/2011/04/27/the-importance-of-zvals-and-circular-references/).

Answer (score 1):

`return &$array;`

But it is fine to just return the $array IMHO

Comment: Because PHP uses Copy-On-Write functionality, there is absolutely no issue just passing the `$array` back.  [Shameless blog plug giving some examples of how PHP handles variables internally](http://www.dereleased.com/2011/04/27/the-importance-of-zvals-and-circular-references/)

Answer (score 0):

Any array returned from a function will be returned by reference until you modify that array before which a copy of the array will be made:

```
$myArray = functionThatReturnsArray(); //$myArray is a reference to the array returned
echo $myArray[0]; //still a reference
$myArray[0] = 'someNewValue'; //from here $myArray will be a copy of the returned array
```

Comment: This is partially correct; when the function returns, the array's ZVal REFCOUNT will be decremented.  PHP will not copy and write, but just write, since the variable containing the function's return value will be the only entry in the symbol table pointing to that ZVal.

Comment: Maybe the word "reference" I used was not appropriate, it is not technically a "reference" more of an "internal reference", read operations on it are actually slightly faster than operations on a normal "reference" abtained like this: `$myArray = &function();`.

Comment: The part about returning by reference is essentially correct; the value created in the function will be the same value pointed to by the variable that is assigned to its return (call it `$foo`).  The part about it then making a copy if you modify it is incorrect; unless you explicitly did something like assigning the contents of the array to something global before returning, then after the function returns only `$foo` will point to it; thus, PHP will **not** copy the value again, it will modify the one location in which it exists.

Comment: @dere Actually in my mind I assumed there is other references to the array other that $myArray itself, like the function returning some static class member data, something like `return self::$data['requestedIndex'];` but in OP's case you're right no copy will be made.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, and yes, in that case there would be a distinct difference between returning by reference and returning by value, since the original value would in fact already be present somewhere else, and would introduce a copy-on-write scenario.  Of course, that does arguably involve storing the value somewhere external to the function (if not globally), and my comments are only taking into account arrays which are constructed initially from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the array type in the argument list (since PHP 5.1), if you do that you can start using it as an array right away:

```
function my_function( array &$arr ) {
    $arr[0] = 'someValue';
}
```

If you don't you should make a check at the top of your function:

```
function my_function( &$arr ) {
    if( !is_array($arr) ) $arr = array(); // or generate an error or throw exception
    $arr[0] = 'someValue';
}
```